# The method setValue(Integer) is undefined for the type Integer?

Tags: java

**MyDate.java** has the method

```
class MyDate {
 public void setValue(Integer value) {
  value = 55;
 }
}
```

**PassTest.java**

```
 import learn.MyDate;

 public class PassTest {
  public static void changeInt(Integer value) {
  setValue(value);
 }
```

is showing the error The method `setValue(Integer)` is undefined for the type `Integer`? why?

And what will be the difference if we call `setValue` as `value.setValue` here?
I tried to find it in google but couldn't understand it?

Comment: You're supposed to call `setValue()` on a `MyDate` object.

Comment: Your method is defined in the wrong class. You might want to use `int` rather than `Integer` to prevent weird issue about Autoboxing. Unless you have a very specific situation, go for the value types.

Comment: Sidenote: Setting the method paramter in method `setValue` has no effect on class-level. Java works on a copy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MyDate {
    private int value;
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
import learn.MyDate;

public class PassTest {
    public static MyDate date = new MyDate();
    public static void changeInt(int value) {
        date.setValue(value);
    }
}
```

As an example.

Answer (score 0):

`PassTest` class is in no way related to `MyDate` why do you expect it to have visibility of a method defined in `MyDate`? Maybe you need to first create an instance of `MyDate` and then call the method on it.